# Icecast stream repeats after interruptions on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, icecast, internet-radio

Running Icecast 2.4.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 with a working source mounted from Darkice default audio card input. Since enabling the intro on the mount in our pertinent config below, we have been getting reports of the stream repeating after an interruption on mobile devices such as Android or iPhone:

```
<limits>
    <clients>3000</clients>
    <sources>10</sources>
    <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
    <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
    <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
    <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
    <!-- If enabled, this will provide a burst of data when a client
         first connects, thereby significantly reducing the startup
         time for listeners that do substantial buffering. However,
         it also significantly increases latency between the source
         client and listening client.  For low-latency setups, you
         might want to disable this. -->
    <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
    <!-- same as burst-on-connect, but this allows for being more
         specific on how much to burst. Most people won't need to
         change from the default 64k. Applies to all mountpoints  -->
    <burst-size>943718</burst-size>
</limits>
<http-headers>
    <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
</http-headers>
<mount>
    <mount-name>/wmnf_high_quality</mount-name>
    <max-listeners>3000</max-listeners>
    <intro>/wmnf_high_quality.mp3</intro>
</mount>
```

I have not been able to duplicate the issue on my Samsung Galaxy s5, when a call or text comes in, the stream picks up where it left off when done with call or notification ends. The intro does repeat as it should after a disconnect/reconnect caused by the interruption, but my stream is still live afterward. Reports say the stream repeats the last 5-10 minutes after interruptions, they can click on the pause/play button to receive live audio again in our app.

Since I'm not able to duplicate, hoping this is just a phone issue for some people. Would anyone be able to suggest what causes the stream to repeat after interruptions?

I'm waiting for feedback to see if this is happening when listening to our website player on a mobile device. The reports so far are from our Android/iPhone app player. I did not develop the app, so I'm not sure of the player. I also asked them to try the stream available in the TuneIn app. Again, I am not able to duplicate myself.

Comment: What is the listener software on those devices? Browser based? Client library?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two independent issues here.  First, let's address the intro file.

There are many players that will automatically reconnect upon connection failure.  This often occurs without any intervention from the user.  A loss of connection is a common occurrence for mobile users.  It's not uncommon when just walking around the house to be connected via WiFi, and then mobile, and then back to WiFi again.  Good players will reconnect and there will often be no (or very little) glitch in the audio stream.  However, adding that intro file creates a pretty serious perceived glitch... your intro file playing repeatedly as this happens.  Therefore, it is strongly recommended that you do *not* use an intro file from your server.  If you wish to have an intro, you can play one on your website where you can accurately detect whether or not the user is starting a new session.

The second issue is that you have an extremely high burst size.  Most players require two seconds of audio data buffered to begin playback.  Players also like to see some consistent audio before they start to playback, to ensure the listener won't have to endure a second round of buffering later on.  Therefore, I usually recommend 5 to 10 seconds of burst size.  In your case at 128k, 10 seconds of buffer is 256 KB.  Your current burst size is nearly a minute long.  This large buffer generally does *not* get flushed to the client as fast as you would like.  The reason is that the player application will provide some backpressure which results in a lower TCP window, which means the server is only able to push so much buffer before the server has to buffer on its end.

I did some quick testing with Wireshark on your `/wmnf_high_quality` stream:

[image: Wireshark Graph for WMNF]

There are two lines plotted... the bytes sent, and the TCP window size.  They mostly follow each other.  At the very beginning of the connection, the window is wide open and the server begins flushing that burst buffer to the client.  Within 1 second though, that window completely closes.  It's not until the player can work through its initial buffer a bit before it opens back up.  The server flushes more of that large buffer, and the window closes again.  Eventually we hit stable playback, and you can see this spikey pattern emerge.  What's happening here is that the player has plenty of buffered data on its end, and will only accept a trickle of data from the server.  The server sends everything it can, but again the window size shrinks to ~1 KB.

In this example at any given time during stable playback, we have a client which probably has around 256 KB - 512 KB of buffered data, and server with nearly 1 MB of total buffer available, spoon-feeding a slow stream to the client from the middle of this buffer.  This should demonstrate that the burst buffer is too large, as it cannot be consumed by the clients fast enough.

Now, the compounding issue which may be causing disconnects.... the queue size.  Icecast doesn't maintain a separate buffer in memory for each individual client.  It has one buffer which it reads from.  The `<queue-size>` value sets the size of this buffer.  If the clients get too far behind, their connection will be dropped.  There is little downside to setting a larger `queue-size`.  Memory on the server is effectively free for the sizes we're talking about, so the consideration comes down to letting users slog through a mediocre connection or just kicking them off completely.  However, your case is a bit different...

By having a large burst size that a client cannot consume, you immediately put the client over the queue size limit, forcing them to be disconnected.  Your listeners are particularly aware of this as they hear the intro message repeatedly, which is maybe why they're reporting it to you now and didn't before.

I'd recommend the following:

- Set your `burst-size` to `252144` (128 kbit * 8 bits-per-byte * 1024 bytes-per-kilobyte * 10 seconds = 256 KB)
- Set your `queue-size` to 4x the `burst-size`.
- Remove the intro file.  Play an intro via code on your website, and not in the stream itself.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed analysis! I will try the setting changes but will have to look into the players for our website and app playing the intro. Neither developed by me. I can't take the intro off without getting that done or an increase in reports. We've really only had one or two and all play well for most. I'll try to get the settings changed tonight and see if we get any noticeable improvement. Even before the intros, we have had more reports of repeats. I have one report on an old tablet that only plays the intro and no stream follows, only one so I'm guessing a device issue.

Comment: @rwfitzy Your old tablet... probably *not* a device issue.  There are probably other clients with the same problem.  Keep in mind that Icecast doesn't send your intro file in realtime.  It reads and flushes the entire thing to the client as fast as possible, not unlike your burst size so there may be a similar problem. 
 Additionally, that stream isn't remuxed or anything so if it has something like an ID3 tag attached, you're essentially just corrupting the stream.  I'd love to know more about the details of the tablet and software you're running on it, if you could share!

Comment: Not my tablet, really wish I could duplicate the issue. User reported it was android samsung, I'll ask the model. They listen via the website. I'll have to ask the engineer if the audio input has any tagging, I'm not doing anything with the input accept mounting his provided input. I only know it's provided via a Delta break out box to installed M Audio Delta 66. He had also said he amplified the signal since we added this Icecast server and he split off from another existing on port 8000. We needed to secure, I'm linux/web pro completely new to the service, so I setup this new server.

Comment: Your audio input is fine, I meant that if the intro file had any ID3 tags in it.  Also... I really miss that series of M-Audio cards.  :-)  Please let me know if I can be of any assistance with your project.  I'm available for consulting.  brad@audiopump.co

Comment: I do know the input is encoded by some Arbitron equipment for ratings.

Comment: Yeah, the PPM signal is fine, it's in the audio itself and won't cause any issue between the intro and stream.