# Icecast: I have strange behaviour with repeats of end of tracks, as well as pitch changes from my Icecast Server

Tags: node.js, networking, audio, server, icecast

I only began using icecast a few days ago, so if I stuffed something up somewhere, please let me know.

I have a weird problem with icecast. Everytime a track is "finished" on icecast, a section of the end of the currently playing track (i think 64kbs of the track) is repeated about 2 to 3 times before the next song plays, but the next song doesn't begin playing in the start, but a few seconds of the way through. Also, I can notice that the playback speed (and hence the pitch) sometimes differs from the original as well.

I consulted [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044717/icecast-stream-keeps-repeating) and [this post that was quoted below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748382/icecast-stream-repeats-after-interruptions-on-mobile-devices) which taught me what the `<burst-on-connect>` and the `<burst-size>` tags are used for. It also taught me this:

> What's happening here is that nothing is being added to the buffer, so clients connect, get the contents of that buffer, and then the stream ends. The client must be re-connecting repeatedly, and it keeps getting that same buffer.

Cheers to Brad for that post. A solution to this problem was provided in a comments section of that post and it said to decrease the `<source-timeout>` of the icecast server, so that it will close the connection quicker and stop any repeating. But this is assuming I want to close the mountpoint, and I dont, because what I am using Icecast for is actually a 24/7 radio player. If I did close my mountpoint, then what happens is VLC just turns off and doesn't repeatedly attempt to connect anymore. Unless this is wrong. I don't know.

I use VLC to hear the playback of the icecast streams and I use [nodeshout](https://github.com/dgurkaynak/nodeshout) which is a bunch of bindings from libshout built for node.js. I use nodeshout to send data to a bunch of mounts on my icecast server. In the future I plan to make a site that will listen to the icecast streams, meaning it will replace VLC.

**icecast.xml**

```
<limits>
        <clients>100</clients>
        <sources>4</sources>
        <queue-size>1008576</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>30</source-timeout>
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
         <burst-size>252144</burst-size>
    </limits>
```

This is a summary of the audio sending code on my node.js server.

**nodejs**

```
// these lines of code is a smaller part of a function, and this sets all the information. The variables name, description etc come from the arguments of the function
    var nodeshout = require("nodeshout");

    let shout = nodeshout.create();
    shout.setHost('localhost');
    shout.setPort(8000);

    shout.setUser('source');
    shout.setPassword(process.env.icecastPassword);  //password in .env file

    shout.setName(name);
    shout.setDescription(description);
    shout.setMount(mount);
    shout.setGenre(genre);

    shout.setFormat(1); // 0=ogg, 1=mp3
    shout.setAudioInfo('bitrate', '128');
    shout.setAudioInfo('samplerate', '44100');
    shout.setAudioInfo('channels', '2');
    return shout



// now meanwhile somewhere lower in the file, there is this summary of how the audio is sent to the icecast server


var nodeshout = require("nodeshout")
var {FileReadStream, ShoutStream} = require("nodeshout") //here is where the FileReadStream and ShoutStream functions come from

const filecontent = new FileReadStream(pathToSong, 65536); //if I change the 65536 to a higher value, then more bytes are being repeated at the end of the track. If I decrease this, it starts sounding buggy and off.  
var streamcontent = filecontent.pipe(new ShoutStream(shoutstream)) 

streamcontent.on('finish', () => {
    next()
    console.log("Track has finished on " + stream.name + ": " + chosenTrack)
})
```

I also notice weirder behaviour. After the previous song had it's last chunk repeated a few times, that's when the server calls the `streamcontent.on('finish')` event that is located in the nodejs script, and only then does it warn me that the track is finished.

**What I have tried**

I tried messing around with the `<source-timeout>` tag, the number of bytes (or bits im not sure) that are being sent on nodejs, the burst size, I also tried turning bursting off completely but it results in super strange behavior.
I also thought creating a new stream every time per song was a bad idea as seen in `new ShoutStream(shoutstream)` when piping the file data, but using the same stream meant that the program would return an error because it would write the next track to the shoutstream after it had said it had closed.

If any more information is necessary to figure out what is going on, I can provide it. Thanks for your time.

Edit: I would like to add: Do you think I should manually control how many bytes are sent to icecast and then use the same stream object instead of calling a new one every time?

Comment: Sounds like your source client is messing up. Try a different one. Also consider switching to Ogg/vorbis or Ogg/Opus.

Comment: @TBR I discovered why my problems were occuring, and I posted it as an answer in this post.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why the stream didn't play some tracks as opposed to others.

**How I got there**

I could not switch to ogg/vorbis or ogg/opus for my stream, so I had to do something with my source client. I double checked everything was correct and that my audio files were in the correct bitrate. When i ran the ffprobe tool with `ffprobe audio.mp3` sometimes the bitrates did not adhere to the typical rates of 120kbps, 128kbps, 192, 312, etc etc so on. It was always some strange value such as 129852 just to provide an example.

I then downloaded the checkmate mp3 checker [here](https://checkmate.gissen.nl/) and checked my audio files, and they were all encoded in a variable bitrate!!! VBR damnit!

**TLDR**

I fixed my problem by re-encoding all my tracks to a constant bitrate of 128kbps using ffmpeg.

Quick Edit: I am pretty sure that programs such as Darkice might already support variable bit rate transfers to Icecast servers, but it would be impractical for me to use darkice, hence why I stuck with nodeshout.

Comment: OK, so the source client didn't do any encoding by itself? If so then yes, you must ensure that all files have exactly matching encoding. It should not matter if it's VBR, CBR or ABR, but it must be consistent, especially the sample rate.